# Javascript replacing a predefined text with a text variable

Tags: javascript

In my code there is a text input that lets the user type in their own text, this text is then turned into a variable;

```
var title = document.getElementById("chartTitle");
var xaxis = document.getElementsByName('xaxis')[0];
var yaxis = document.getElementsByName('yaxis')[0];
```

Now that the variables contain the text, I need to change two parts within this code to make it so the predefined "text" is replaced with the text within the variable. The two parts are "title text" must changed to be the var title and the "yaxis text" must be changed to the var yaxis.

```
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title:{
      text: "title text"
    },
    axisY: {
      title: "yaxis text"
    },
    data: [{
         type: "column",
         dataPoints: []
    }]
});
chart.render();
}
```

Comment: add an event listener for those elements such as "change" or "keyup" events, and inside the function set the `title.text` etc. to the .textContent of those elements (you can use `this` inside the function).

Comment: Can you not simply set the correct text in the first place, ie `title: { text: title }, axisY: { title: yaxis }`?

Comment: can you add your html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding id to your inputs to access them faster using `document.getElementById`:

```
<input type="text" name="yaxis" id="yaxis">
```

Note that the functions `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByName` return DOM elements rather than their text. To access the content of text input element use its proerty `value`.

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title:{
      text: title.value
    },
    axisY: {
      title: yaxis.value
    },
    data: [{
         type: "column",
         dataPoints: []
    }]
});
chart.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables do not contain the text; they contain only the elements.

If you're going to select a single element, it's better to use `querySelector` instead of one of the HTMLCollection methods:

```
const xAxisElement = document.querySelector('[name=xaxis]');
const yAxisElement = document.querySelector('[name=yaxis]');
```

Then to get their *values*, you need to use .value:

```
const xAxisValue = xAxisElement.value;
const yAxisValue = yAxisElement.value;
```

*Then* you can proceed to do things with `xAxisValue` and `yAxisValue`.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding correctly that you need to use the variables you defined earlier for the elements, and extract the value, just put them on your code like this:

```
var title = document.getElementById("chartTitle").value;
var xaxis = document.getElementsByName('xaxis')[0].value;
var yaxis = document.getElementsByName('yaxis')[0].value;

 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title:{
      text: title
    },
    axisY: {
      title: yaxis
    },
    data: [{
         type: "column",
         dataPoints: []
    }]
});
chart.render();
}
```